# ¿Cómo hacer una petición a través de postman o insomnia a la API de mercado pago?

Tags: api, post, mercadopago, postman

Estuve probando la API usan la siguiente CURL:

> curl -X POST -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type:
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
> "https://api.mercadopago.com/oauth/token?client_secret=TEST-7278820777929276-112400-87a9751d1572934a08f4134b692ae467-151662073&grant_type=authorization_code&code=TG-5fc9d49580e35b00066efc32-682439399&redirect_uri=https://localhost:4200/registromaestros

Pero quisiera saber como puedo probar esta API usando postman o insomnia para poder enviar el body en forma del siguiente JSON:

```
{
    "client_secret": "TEST-7278820777929276-112400-87a9751d1572934a08f4134b692ae467-151662073",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "code": "TG-5fc9d49580e35b00066efc32-682439399"
}
```

Intente hacer la petición a través de postman, pero solo pude obtener este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás seguro que esas son las credenciales para esa API? Porque es exactamente lo que arroja Postman!

Comment: si, cuando probe el curl con esas credenciales no me arrojo ningun problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con *Insomnia* debería ser así, en la pestaña *Body* seleccionas *JSON* y luego colocas tu payload en la caja de texto.

[image: Insomnia]

Esto es con *Postman*, recuerda que aquí debes enviar el contenido como `raw` e indicarle que está formateado como *JSON*.
[image: Postman]

Agregué `redirect_uri` en ambos casos porque me decía que es requerido.